# How to hide another app's UI element or View in android

Tags: android

Let's make this straight. I am trying to create an app where the user will be able to inspect UI elements/Views of other apps and simply change the View visibility to `SHOW/HIDE/GONE`.

So these are my questions

- Is it possible to change visibility of other app's UI elements ?
- If yes, which API is responsible for it ?
- If no built-in API available, is it possible to do using root access ?
- If yes, How can I do that?

I searched the web, couldn't find anything positive.
Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: "Is it possible to change visibility of other app's UI elements ? " -- no. Examining and modifying the UI of another app is not generally supported, for privacy and security reasons. "is it possible to do using root access ?" -- possibly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have any idea on how to do that it using root access ?

Comment: I'm curious what's your use-case though, why would you need that behavior? Are you writing an adblocker app?

Comment: @azizbekian Sorry for the VERY late reply. Yes. I was trying to create an AdBlocker :D